# Create a database using PHP or phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to web development, and for the college thesis I'm going to create an online system that uses a database. My question is: how should one create a database?

**a)** Using PHP such as:

```
<?php

$servername = "host_name";
$username = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$link = connectToMySql($servername, $username, $password) or die( " Unable to connect to server ");

$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname";
if (executeSQLQuery($query))
{
 echo "Database <b>$dbname</b> created successfully <br />";
}
else
{
 echo "Error in creating database: <br/><br/>". launchError();
}

?>
```

**b)** Or using phpMyAdmin (creating manually database and tables)?

Which approach is the best? Which one should be used and why (Advantages, disadvantages)?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You should focus on other things than that. As long as users don't have access to creation scripts I highly doubt that it matters

Comment: Unless you're on a dedicated system, you probably don't have permission to run `CREATE DATABASE` anyway. Even on a dedi that might be a root-locked action.

Comment: In a professional setting you should/will use a *migration framework* for your database schema which will be executed by a deploy user when a new version of your app is rolled out to your server(s). This may or may not be completely overkill for whatever you're doing. We can't tell you. The goal should always be *automated repeatability* though.

Comment: Thanks esequew, I changed the name of the functions because the intention of the question was to decide if it's better to create a database by code or manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a thesis, it hardly matters.

For normal development, if you are the only user of your software, then it is probably easiest to maintain it in a maintenance tool like PHPMyAdmin, because you can create and update it in a very visual way.

Creating it in software is especially useful as an installation feature. Some common software, like Wordpress and MediaWiki create their own database and even have smart scripts that update the database structure when a new version has additional requirements. But building something like that is also tricky and time-consuming, so unless you want to have such an installer feature, it is probably not worth the effort.

Also note, that for proper database management, you'll want to have different users with different rights. You may want to make your software connect using database credentials that only have rights to edit data (not structure), and only connect using a more powerful user if you have to update the database structure. But that probably also doesn't apply for a thesis, unless it is specifically about access control management.

Comment: This system is going to be used on a large scale and there will be an entry in the database for each user. The system has been commissioned, that's why I asked the question. I'm not sure if I also need to give them a php script to automatically setup the database for the first time.